# Download (export) WorldPop data for a specific region and year using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am trying to download (export) *WorldPop* data (population count at 100m spatial resolution) for 2018 for the city of London, using `Google Earth Engine` (`GEE`). The *WorldPop* is a yearly dataset.

There is no example available so I tried this (among other things):

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'));
  
var bands = 'population'
  
var visualization = {
  bands: ['population'],
  palette: ['24126c', '1fff4f', 'd4ff50']
};

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'Population');
  
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset,
  description: 'pop',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  crs: 'EPSG:27700',
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Error: Image.setDefaultProjection, argument 'image': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)
```

which means I am trying to export the entire image collection (I don't want that). How can I export the population of London for the year 2018?

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0f54f592c5caf7c271f1508886be0c25) is the link to my code and [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/nikostziokas/london_27700) is the link to the asset.

Comment: A filtered collection is still a collection.  You want to take the `.first()` element of the collection and export that.

Comment: `var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
  .filterBounds(table)
  .select('population')
  .first()
  .clip(table);`
It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the image from the collection. What I do here is use the table to filter the collection spatially. Then I convert the image collection to an image list, and finally, I extract the image from the list to export it.

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')).filterBounds(table);

//Convert to collection list
var list_img = dataset.toList(dataset.size());

// Select the image on the collection list
var img = ee.Image(list_img.get(0)); // or any image of your preference

 var bands = 'population'
  
var visualization = {
  bands: ['population'],
  palette: ['24126c', '1fff4f', 'd4ff50']
};

 Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'Population');
  
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: img,
  description: 'pop',
  scale: 100,
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1000000000000,
  crs: 'EPSG:27700',
  folder: 'Landsat-5'
});
```

Comment: You should not convert the collection to list (or use collection.size() to determine how big the list should be).  Both are potentially expensive and unnecessary.  `collection.first()` is what you should use.

Comment: After ```collection.filterBounds``` I get 3 images: features: List (3 elements)
0: Image WorldPop/GP/100m/pop/GRB_2018 (1 band)
1: Image WorldPop/GP/100m/pop/RUS_2018 (1 band)
2: Image WorldPop/GP/100m/pop/USA_2018 (1 band). Then, how to get image 1 or 2 without expensive and unnecessary computations? @Noel Gorelick

Comment: You can mosaic() those together if you need them all (they're different regions).